# Blueprism Failing To Read From Clipboard

Tags: clipboard, blueprism

I have a Blueprism process which is generating a pdf report from a CRM application. The process highlights the text, copies and then uses GetClipboard(). It is producing an error of Requested Clipboard Operation did not succeed.

If I run the GetClipboard again it seems to work. This is causing issues at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process was running too fast. Essentially the copy had completed when it was trying to run GetClipboard(). Solution was to put a delay between the steps.